# Use a reverse proxy do record all incoming HTTP request, then execute it in a clone server for performance testing

Tags: linux, testing, proxy, webserver, jmeter

I find this issue on [performance testing on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/192785/use-a-reverse-proxy-do-record-all-incoming-http-request-then-execute-it-in-a-cl).

I used to do performance testing with Jmeter. Can it it record all the requests to my online server?

Comment: wouldn't it make much more sense to ask there ? or comment on that question ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach can be used with JMeter Access Log Sampler for Get requests but in my opinion it is not as realistic as it sounds.

Because data used at the time of proxying interception can have changed meanwhile so just replaying traffic will not simulate initial traffic and can generate errors that would not happen in real life.
Finally  if test does not check these can lead to too optimistic response time.